# Is there a more efficient way to use REGEXP across multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, regex, simplify, mysql-5.6

In a MySQL 5.6 database, I'm trying to write a script that will find and remove stray punctuation (lone spaces, lone commas, etc.) from the end of each field. Currently, I have something like this:

```
UPDATE exampletable
SET Column1=TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM Column1)),
    Column2=TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM Column2)),
    Column3=TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM Column3)),
    Column4=TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM Column4))
WHERE Column1 REGEXP " $|,$"
    OR Column2 REGEXP " $|,$"
    OR Column3 REGEXP " $|,$"
    OR Column4 REGEXP " $|,$"
```

...which works well enough. However, I'd like to write a version that checks a lot more columns, and given that I'm running exactly the same search on every single column, it'd be great to find a more elegant method than just pasting in the same regex thirty or forty times. (MATCH, perhaps? Is that compatible with regex?)

Is there any good way to streamline this code? Unfortunately, given the nature of the rather-specialized platform, the best solution would have to fit in a single query (though UNION, etc., are fair game). I'd definitely like to hear any procedure- or routine-based solutions, but they're ultimately suboptimal.

Comment: Why not systematically trim all columns without a `where` condition?

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this. You can use dynamic SQL to construct the query based on the column list in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte , that'll do it! Ha. Thank you!